# Set default sort order in Pageable request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to use this code with [specification-arg-resolver](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver) with `@PageableDefault(sort = "createdAt", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC)` in order to implement search and to set sort order but it's not working. I tried this:

```
    @GetMapping("find")
    public Page<PaymentTransactionsDTO> getAllBySpecification(
            @PageableDefault(sort = "createdAt", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC)
            @And({
                    @Spec(path = "unique_id", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class)

            }) Specification<PaymentTransactions> specification,
            Pageable pageable
    ) {        
        return transactionService.getAllBySpecification(specification, pageable));       
    }
```

Do you know how I can set the sort order with annotations into the above code>

Comment: Did you enable it?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver#enabling-spec-annotations-in-your-spring-app

Comment: Yes, I did. I can make some basic filtering.

Comment: But sort order is not working.

Comment: I didn't use that lib. I just checked it out at a glance and configuration comes up to my mind. Sorry I can't help

Comment: What lib for search functionality do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193600/discussion-between-ebrahim-pasbani-and-peter-penzov).

Comment: Try to debug at line `return transactionService.getAllBySpecification(specification, pageable)); ` and observer value of 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the library but I strongly expect the `@DefaultPageable` annotation needs to go on the `Pageable` argument.